# Form population and validation using AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Update: I figured out how to populate the form with default data. How would I go about populating error messages when the data entered is invalid (when Submit is clicked)?

Comment: For your syntax error, look at `$.ajax{...`. Something should come before the `{`. Otherwise, form validation + AJAX is a broad issue with many, many resources online. I'd suggest you get to reading.

Comment: Should it be $.ajax(... ?

Comment: Could you or someone please point me somewhere to the syntax of this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

In line 5 you have forgotten a `(`. This block's line:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("#InsertDefault").click(function() { 

$.ajax{url: "backend.php?act=default", success: function(result) { 
    console.log($.parseJSON(result)); 
    data = $.parseJSON(result); 
    document.getElementById("name").value = data["name"]; 
});
```

This:

```
$.ajax{url: "backend.php?act=default", success: function(result) { //...
```

Should be:

```
$.ajax({url: "backend.php?act=default", success: function(result) { //...
//    ↑
```

Comment: @DBMP, oops, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: It's better to use done method of promise instead of success callback. You can read about this here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your ajax call like below..
As Nitai Pointed out you missed '(' before ajax.

Also look for other closing brackets also as i can see they look suspicious in your program.

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 

      $("#InsertDefault").click(function() { 
         $.ajax({url: "backend.php?act=default", success: function(result) { 
            console.log($.parseJSON(result)); 
            data = $.parseJSON(result); 
            document.getElementById("name").value = data["name"]; 
        }
    });
```